# Split one dataframe to multiple sub-dataframes based on common columns in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Assuming the dataframe `df` as follows:

```
            ISIN  Coupon  Issue Date Maturity Date  Jan 18th  Jan 19th  \
0   CA135087A610  0.0150   7/30/2012      6/1/2023    103.13    103.14   
1   CA135087F254  0.0075  10/19/2015      3/1/2021    100.08    100.08   
2   CA135087F585  0.0075   4/11/2016      9/1/2021    100.40    100.40   
3   CA135087G328  0.0050  10/11/2016      3/1/2022    100.44    100.43   
4   CA135087H490  0.0175   10/6/2017      3/1/2023    103.29    130.29   
5   CA135087ZU15  0.0275    8/2/2011      6/1/2022    103.61    103.60   
6   CA135087J546  0.0225   10/5/2018      3/1/2024    106.21    106.21   
7   CA135087J967  0.0150    4/5/2019      9/1/2024    104.27    104.28   
8   CA135087K528  0.0125  10/11/2019      3/1/2025    103.60    103.60   
9   CA135087K940  0.0050    4/3/2020      9/1/2025    100.33    100.32   
10  CA135087L518  0.0025   10/9/2020      3/1/2026     98.78     98.77   

    Jan 20th  
0     103.10  
1     100.08  
2     100.39  
3     100.41  
4     103.25  
5     103.57  
6     106.17  
7     104.25  
8     103.59  
9     100.30  
10     98.76
```

I need to split it into 3 sub-dataframes based on common columns `ISIN`, `Coupon`, `Issue Date`, `Maturity Date`.

```
common_columns = ['ISIN', 'Coupon', 'Issue Date', 'Maturity Date']
df1.columns = common_columns + 'Jan 18th'
df2.columns = common_columns + 'Jan 19th'
df3.columns = common_columns + 'Jan 20th'
```

Then save them to an excel file, with sheet_name `Jan 18th`, `Jan 19th` and `Jan 20th`. Please note that in real data there are other date columns `Jan 21th`, `Jan 22th`, etc.

To save the dataframes:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer, 'Jan 18th')
df2.to_excel(writer, 'Jan 19th')
df3.to_excel(writer, 'Jan 20th')
writer.save()
```

How could I do that in Python? Thanks.

**Update:**

For first sheet's `ISIN` replaced by `2021-01-18`, Jan 18th by `Close Price`, second sheet's `ISIN` replaced by `2021-01-19`, Jan 19th by `Close Price`, third sheet's `ISIN` replaced by `2021-01-20`, Jan 20th by `Close Price`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `index.difference` to get the date like columns by removing `comm_columns` from the dataframe, then for each date like column use `DataFrame.to_excel` along with `pd.ExcelWriter` to create sheets:

```
comm_cols = ['ISIN', 'Coupon', 'Issue Date', 'Maturity Date']
date_cols = df.columns.difference(comm_cols)

with pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx') as writer:
    for col in date_cols:
        sub_df = df[comm_cols + [col]]
        sub_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=col)
        
    writer.save()
```

UPDATE: To `rename` the column `ISIN` while saving the sheet use:

```
comm_cols = ['ISIN', 'Coupon', 'Issue Date', 'Maturity Date']
isin_cols = ['2021-01-18', '2021-02-18', '2021-02-19']
date_cols = df.columns.difference(comm_cols)

with pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx') as writer:
    for col, isin_col in zip(date_cols, isin_cols):
        sub_df = df[comm_cols + [col]].rename(columns={'ISIN': isin_col})
        sub_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=col)
        
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to modify each sub-dataframe's columns with `'2021-01-18', 'Coupon', 'Issue Date', 'Maturity Date', 'Close Price'` for df1, `'2021-01-19', 'Coupon', 'Issue Date', 'Maturity Date', 'Close Price'` for `df2`, etc. before saving to excel?

Comment: This means I need rename `ISIN` with `2021-01-18, etc`, and `Jan 18th` renamed by `Close Price` for `df1`.

Comment: Great, could u please add the code for that?

Comment: @ahbon Can you provide the list of new names which are to be mapped on the ISIN column?

Comment: @ahbon Updated the answer as per your requirements.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the last column for each sheet didn't rename to 'Close Price'?

Comment: By adding `sub_df.rename(columns = {sub_df.columns[-1]: "close price"}, inplace = True)`, it seems not working out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228375/discussion-between-shubham-sharma-and-ahbon).